# How can I send keyboard input thorugh SSH to a windows machine?

Tags: windows, ssh, keyboard, openssh

So, I have two computers at home, both with Windows , and I'm trying to learn how to send inputs from one to another. When I used linux, it was as simple as using xdotool over SSH. But in windows I find it a little more problematic.

After searching a little, I found out how to do a simple "eject" command:

`powershell (New-Object -com "WMPlayer.OCX.7").cdromcollection.item(0).eject()`

And the line above would actually work (locally and while in SSH session), but this one:

`powershell -c "$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys('TEST')`

Didn't seem to do anything while over SSH (but it did work locally on the machine).

Is it not possible to send keyboard inputs to windows while in SSH? If so, is there another way?

Comment: Why do you want to send keyboard inputs?

Comment: Just to know how much I can automate in a project. Recently I've had some school work that, if I could send inputs directly to every single one of those windows machines at the same time and fill their formularies, would be a lot better than to input one by one.